# Oracle: update statement

Tags: oracle, sql-update

I have the following simple update

```
    UPDATE INVOICE
    SET INV_SUBTOTAL = V_SUBTOTAL
    WHERE INV_ID = I_INV_ID;
```

How can I declare the `i_inv_id` like add it an alias since i am relating it to another table called bookings. something like;

```
UPDATE INVOICE
        SET INV_SUBTOTAL = V_SUBTOTAL
        WHERE INVOICE.INV_ID = BOOKINGS.INV_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use construction like this:

UPDATE INVOICE
        SET INV_SUBTOTAL = V_SUBTOTAL
        WHERE INVOICE.INV_ID IN (SELECT B.INV_ID FROM BOOKINGS V WHERE ....) ;